# Изменение цены с помощью jquery

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь сделать следующее: при нажатии на input, его value должно прибавляться к value другого input'а, тем самым увеличивая цену.
Пытался так но не прибавляется

```
$(function(){
    var vall = $(".site-viz").val();
    var val = $(".wet").val();
    $(".wet").click(function(){
        $(".site_viz").val(vall + val);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенесите получение значений в функцию. Сейчас вы вычисляете сумму значений, которые были при загрузке страницы

[**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3mcra02e/)

```js
$(function(){
    $(".wet").click(function(){
        var vall = $(".site_viz").val();
        var val = $(".wet").val();
        $(".site_viz").val(parseInt(vall)+parseInt(val));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="site_viz" value="3500"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="wet" value="1500" />
```

**Update**

```js
$(function(){
$(".wet").change(function(){
    var vall = $(".site_viz").val();
    var val = $(".wet").val();
    if(this.checked)
       $(".site_viz").val(parseInt(vall)+parseInt(val));
    else
       $(".site_viz").val(parseInt(vall)-parseInt(val));
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="site_viz" value="3500"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="wet" value="1500" />
```

Comment: выводит undefined1500

Comment: как выглядит html с вашими  .site-viz и .wet элементами

Comment: <input class="site_viz" value="3500"> <input type="checkbox" class="wet" value="1500"  />

Comment: я обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, работает, только стал использовать Number(), теперь не подскажете как сделать так чтобы при повторном нажатии на чекбокс цена обратно отнималась?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3mcra02e/1/

Comment: Не обновил jsfiddle в прошлый раз. Сейчас смотрите